# Counting rows of Dataframe filtering by combinations of levels

Tags: r, subset

I've this data frame (which is the output of multibedintersect between 8 different Bed files of my ChIp-seq data):

```
    head(Table,)
    chrom   start     end num  list
2   chr1 4491607 4493602   2   6,7
6   chr1 4571540 4571826   2   7,8
15  chr1 5019126 5020672   2   2,7
21  chr1 7139275 7139745   3 4,6,7
23  chr1 7398185 7398658   2   7,8
28  chr1 9745462 9745912   4 1,4,6,7
```

The column "list" is a character string that represents the presence of that particular peak in the list of my samples.

**For example, the peak "2" is found in either sample number 6 and 7.**

I want to count how many times every combination of 2 samples are found in the dataset, creating a table that summaries the information.

So basically multibedintersect gives back too many overlaps. I'm just interested in how the samples overlap with each-other 2 at the time.

For example, the samples **6 and 7** are found in either peak **2,21,28** and the samples **4 and 6** are found in the peaks **21 and 28**

Via the package tydiverse, I'm able to address the issue for 1 sample at the time but I'm not able to "make it cycle" for every combination.

```
     Table %>%
  filter(str_detect(list, "6,7"))
```

In this way I get back anything that has that combination:

```
   chrom   start     end num  list
2   chr1 4491607 4493602   2   6,7
21  chr1 7139275 7139745   3 4,6,7
28  chr1 9745462 9745912   4 1,4,6,7
```

I think this is underperforming and very script intensive, as I would need to manually filter for every combination: 
To name a few:

- 7,8
- 6,8
- 5,8
- 4,8
- 3,8
- 2,8
- 1,8
- 6,7
- Continues

Doing this "my way" would be something horrible like this:

```
Counts <- NULL
Pippo <- Table %>%
  filter(str_detect(list, "7,8"))
Counts <- cbind(nrow(Pippo))

Pippo <- Table %>%
  filter(str_detect(list, "6,8"))
Counts <- cbind(Counts, nrow(Pippo))

Pippo <- Table %>%
  filter(str_detect(list, "5,8"))
Counts <- cbind(Counts, nrow(Pippo))

Pippo <- Table %>%
  filter(str_detect(list, "4,8"))
Counts <- cbind(Counts, nrow(Pippo))

Pippo <- Table %>%
  filter(str_detect(list, "3,8"))
Counts <- cbind(Counts, nrow(Pippo))

Pippo <- Table %>%
  filter(str_detect(list, "2,8"))
Counts <- cbind(Counts, nrow(Pippo))

Pippo <- Table %>%
  filter(str_detect(list, "1,8"))
Counts <- cbind(Counts, nrow(Pippo))
```

Would you please suggest me a better way to count every combination and create this data frame of summary?

Thanks a Lot

Comment: do you want only consecutive occurences? for example if the value of list is `4, 6 ,7` would that count for `4, 7` or only for `4, 6` and `6, 7`?

Comment: for the 3 the of them! SO for 
4,7
6,7
4,6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider base R with two `sapply` calls: one with `combn` to build all pair strings and then another with `grepl` for subsetting data frame to retrieve row counts:

```
pairs <- sapply(combn(1:8, 2, simplify=FALSE), function(i) paste(i, collapse=","))

Counts <- sapply(pairs, function(i) nrow(subset(Table, grepl(i, `list`))))

Counts
# 1,2 1,3 1,4 1,5 1,6 1,7 1,8 2,3 2,4 2,5 2,6 2,7 2,8 3,4 3,5 3,6 3,7 3,8 4,5 4,6 
#   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2 
# 4,7 4,8 5,6 5,7 5,8 6,7 6,8 7,8 
#   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   2
```

Alternatively, with a tidy version (`dplyr` + `purrr`):

```
pairs <- combn(1:8, 2, simplify=FALSE) %>% 
  map(~(paste(., collapse=","))) %>%
  unlist()

Counts <- pairs %>% 
  map(~(filter(Table, str_detect(list, .)) %>% nrow)) %>%
  setNames(pairs) %>%
  unlist()

Counts
# 1,2 1,3 1,4 1,5 1,6 1,7 1,8 2,3 2,4 2,5 2,6 2,7 2,8 3,4 3,5 3,6 3,7 3,8 4,5 4,6 
#   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2 
# 4,7 4,8 5,6 5,7 5,8 6,7 6,8 7,8 
#   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   2
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. 

I'm so bad with Sapply : ( 

Is there a video tutorial you would recommend? Thanks so much again!